# Abort or stop stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Any T-SQL command to abort or stop the running stored procedure from other window?

Note : not using RaiseError

Comment: You can kill the SPID.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's always the best way to do this, but it certainly works for me: Check the SPID of the running Procedure (for example by executing sp_who2). Let's say the SPID  is 92. Afterwards, you can execute the statement KILL 92.